# Why .proto file only showing line one as " syntax = "proto3" in vs code version 1.70.2

Tags: visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers, grpc-go

I was following an online class on grpc! And the tutorer drop a github link, consisting of a .proto files, of what he taught us but when I pull the github everything looks ok but when I try to open with vs code version 1.70.2 it'll open but only showing the first line of the .proto file.
Syntax = "proto3"

I try re-install the grpc plugins from inside vs code because I use gitbash to set up my grpc and as well to pull the repo.
But the re-intall didn't work I don't know what to do again

Comment: This problem is not a good fit for this site, as it is likely some setup problem on your system that is practically impossible to solve based on the information you have provided.